# How to dump and load object with private fields in c#?

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, deserialization

I want to refactor a legacy project and have a huge method. No one knows what the method does exactly. My plan is to dump the objects from the parameter list and the returned object and load them again for a test. In that way I can assure that while refactoring nothing changes.

But the specific objects have private fields and I can't change them (to make them serializable). I can use something like [ObjectDumper](https://github.com/thomasgalliker/ObjectDumper) to dump the object with private fields but I don't know how to load the object again.

Do anyone know a library that does that for me?

Comment: Due to the fact that you can't change the class itself I would try to write a [custom JSON converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0) that uses reflection to access all fields and writes them down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use binary serialization:

```cs
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

#pragma warning disable 618
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(ms, data);
#pragma warning restore 618
```

You'll get a warning that this method is obsolete, but it works just fine in all environments I use (certainly up to .NET 6.0).

Comment: It's not that `BinaryFormatter` won't work but rather that it's insecure. Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide). If security is not an issue then that won't be a problem but it's a good idea to stop using insecure options at all so you can't possibly use one when you shouldn't. Based on the question, security is probably not an issue here but, if there are secure alternatives that aren't significantly more complex then they are better alternatives.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot annotate the objects as serializable (what is required to use binaryformatter). I do not have access to the class files. Is there a way without changing the classes?

Comment: @SaschaDörflein I didn't remember that requirement, sorry. Is it possible to derive from the classes in question? You could derive from them and add the [Serializable] attribute. Doesn't work in case you have a tree of instances, though.